# Why do we not develop tolerance to endogenous factors?

Tags: pharmacology, endocrinology

In pharmacology, we studied the development of tolerance to the therapeutic effects of drugs. It is defined as the diminished response of the body to a drug as an adaptation to its continued presence.

However, the factors like enzymes and hormones (either autocrine, paracrine, or endocrine) are also continuously present throughout the body in a steady state concentration or fluctuating concentrations (depending on the function and homeostatic requirements). So why, and how, does the body not develop tolerance to its own enzymes and hormones?

Comment: There's a false premise here. Sometimes we do develop a tolerance for our own enzymes, etc. Obviously, this is not healthy.

Comment: I find your question unanswerable without your *naming a specific example of a drug* to which the body develops tolerance, and a *specific example* of  a (preferably similar) molecule (what you call a "factor") that you think should invoke a similar tolerance but does not, *explaining why think it should*. The key to this, in my opinion, is the molecular mechanism for this "tolerance". I suspect you and others may be approaching this from the wrong angle and the question to ask yourself is why should another compound have such a mechanism, not why it lacks this.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Tolerance is just a special case of [homeostasis](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeostasis). There definitely is some level of "tolerance" to endogenous substances: down-regulation or desensitization of receptors that are over-activated, negative feedback loops, etc, are ubiquitous in biology.

The mechanisms that manifest as tolerance to exogenous substances are often part of endogenous homeostatic pathways.

Commenter bob1 mentions [insulin resistance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insulin_resistance) as a classic case of "endogenous tolerance", and it's quite an important one as it results in type 2 diabetes.

For another example, the most common excitatory neurotransmitter in the brain is glutamate; too much glutamate release or excitatory responses that are too strong result in seizures. There are several pathways that you could consider contributing to "glutamate tolerance", including [particular glutamate receptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metabotropic_glutamate_receptor) that downregulate [other glutamate receptors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ionotropic_glutamate_receptor): when neurons are exposed to a lot of glutamate at once, they reduce their responsiveness to glutamate in the near future. Failures in this regulatory/tolerance pathway are one cause of epilepsy.

A third generalized example is that of [receptor-mediated endocytosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Receptor-mediated_endocytosis), which can serve to import specific things into the cell when they bind with a receptor, but is also important in regulating the overall strength of signaling pathways. Whether a ligand is exogenous or endogenous, when binding a receptor causes internalization of that receptor there is one fewer receptor available to bind additional ligand.

Comment: Bryan “…are often part of endogenous homeostatic pathways”. How many people will have a clue what this means? You work hard for this site. Give it a rest.

Comment: The classic example would be insulin resistance. This leads to hyperinsulinemia and can result in type 2 diabetes if the resistance gets too high.

Comment: +1. I think a pharmacology student should be able to understand your answer, however I doubt most lay persons will. Please forgive me for explaining it/dumbing it down.

Comment: @David "Endogenous" is in the question; "homeostatic/homeostasis" is linked in my answer and also in the OP - I think it's reasonable to expect someone to understand that word or read more until they do; "pathway" is, hopefully, a word that someone studying biology would encounter regularly.

Comment: This does not seem to provide a good reason to the actual question. Yes, the body regulates its internal functioning properly to achieve some usually near-optimal -- under the given circumstances -- dynamic balance. But why does it find a balance with endogenous substances, like endogenous opioids, which does not involve developing a tolerance, while a tolerance *is* developed for synthetic opioids? Saying "it's the usual mechanisms, nothing to see here" does not seem to cut the mustard. (Oh, I see you edited the answer in the meantime. It is a bit more specific now.)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica What makes you think there is not a balance found with synthetic opioids? It may not be the "desired" balance for someone seeking a euphoric drug experience or a physician using opioids for pain relief, of course. And, it may be desirable to have *more* tolerance than actually observed for some common side effects like constipation.

Comment: A balance, yes, but one that involves tolerance. As opposed to the balance found with endogenous opioids. (IIUC the endogenous ones are scrubbed quickly by receptors etc., which is why no tolerance develops. Such specific differences are causal.)

Comment: @Peter-ReinstateMonica Here's an example of a paper about tolerance to endogenous opioids: https://link.springer.com/article/10.1186/s40360-017-0193-y They claim evidence that tolerance of NSAID pain relief is mediated through reduced sensitivity to endogenous opioids. So, it isn't that tolerance can't or doesn't occur with response to the endogenous signals. Just that, when everything is "working properly", the body is somewhere near a homeostatic equilibrium. You need to perturb it or find a case of dysfunction to notice the regulation happening.

Comment: @David This feels like an appropriately technical answer to a technical question on a technical site. I don't understand what rest you think Bryan is supposed to give.

Comment: I suspect that the Emperor is naked. Bryan, just because the poster used an imprecise word, doesn't mean you should. I think this is an unclear question which according to SE policy should not be answered until the poster clarifies (as I comment to him). I respect your work on this site, but expected a hard molecular answer from you. And @fredsbend —  I don't think this is a technical question, but a naive question from a student who should be encouraged to do more preparation and give more precision to his thoughts.

Comment: @David The concepts and accompanying jargon make it technical, both vernacularly and technically. A false premise from a learner doesn't change that. If something is specifically wrong in this answer you should focus on that.

Comment: @David I don't know, I think the question is a bit naïve to a biology professional, yes, but also insightful for a biology student given how these things are often taught in a biology/pharmacology classroom: it's likely that the concept of tolerance was introduced, and examples given, but the connection was not made between tolerance and regulation within biological systems more broadly. OP noticed that something didn't quite sit right, and asked a question about this conflict in their understanding.

Comment: I may be asking a naive question.  But I think the body has some ability to distinguish between foreign and self substances. It would probably perceive a foreign unusual drug as harmful and actually work towards building tolerance to it. A naturally found  substance in the body if useful will not stimulate body to build resistance Right? Otherwise people with allergies wouldn't have to suffer so much

Comment: Like the answer below says,  the body regulates endogenous factors so it is not noticed.  I think the body would create new receptors try to undo damage to the old ones and  more to reverse tolerance to something useful produced by the body. Otherwise hormone requirements and production should increase rather largely with age. Right? Insulin resistance is again a counter to what I said so IDK

Comment: Chemistry is chemistry. A given chemical is no different depending on how it's produced. Something exogenous might be different because it's in a different place or in a different concentration but otherwise there cannot be any difference in the effect of the same chemical. That doesn't mean that the response to any chemical is to respond less in the future - that's a response to "too much", wherever it's produced. Of course sometimes it's possible to get it "wrong" because our bodies are just chemistry, they don't have the ability to see the future.

Comment: Yes thats true. What i meant by foreign was something chemically similar or producing chemically simar effects as a substance produced by the body? Like body will probably promote tolerance, resistance to and removal of a drug but not whatever is it's analogue is in the human body.

Comment: @Aurelius Even endogenous neurotransmitters result in a regulatory response the same as tolerance, when they are present at a high concentration or for a long time. That's what I wrote in this answer. I'd suggest trying to grasp this concept rather than assuming it's not true. If you study biology you'll find these regulatory pathways absolutely everywhere. It's a basic defining principle of how biology works. See also the concept of "negative feedback loops".

Answer (score 4):

@Brian Krause's answer is completely correct. I'm only going to simplify it.

Tolerance to drugs develops because the enzymatic pathways (which are already in existence in the body, i.e. "are... endogenous homeostatic pathways") responsible for its metabolism enabling its removal from the body are increased, either by increased rate of metabolism or increased production of the enzyme(s) responsible for the drug's metabolism, etc. One of the most widely known such enzymatic pathways is the Cytochrome P450 pathway. (These are not the only ways tolerance develop, just the easier ways to measure.)

Tolerance to drugs is more noticeable because most drugs are xenobiotic, i.e. substances foreign to the body (or "exogenous substances"), so we must ingest them to get the intended effect, and the effect is noticeable, so when tolerance starts to develop, the dosage must be changed. So it's easy to observe tolerance to drugs. However, substances produced by the body are regulated without our being aware of it, because we're not visibly or otherwise noticeably actively doing anything; our bodies are to constantly compensating for internal processes, e.g. regulating our blood pH, glucose levels, etc. In a healthy individual, this is normal homeostatis, e.g. through positive and negative feedback, up- or down-regulation of substances produces, etc.. You mentioned hormones; thyroxine is a good example. Thyroxine is needed by nearly every cell in the body. The pituitary gland monitors (and controls) blood levels of thyroxine through the production of thyroid stimulating hormone  (TSH) Low levels of thyroxine stimulate the  production of TSH, whereas high levels causes decreased TSH production. of We're just unaware of all the regulation our body does until it overwhelms our ability to maintain homeostasis and becomes a problem of some sort, e.g. hyper/hypothyroidism, T2D (type 2 diabetes.), etc.

<sub>[Cytochrome P450 Structure, Function and Clinical Significance: A Review](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/28124606/)</sub>
<sub>[Drug Metabolism](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK442023/)</sub>
<sub>[Physiology, Thyroid Stimulating Hormone](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK499850/)</sub>

Comment: Thank you, this is a great companion answer. I think you stated the most important concept for OP to recognize when you write "*the effect is noticeable, so when tolerance starts to develop, the dosage must be changed. So it's easy to observe tolerance to drugs*". That seems to be the main difference with exogenous factors: they can be changed quickly and the effects observed. If you did the same with synthetic versions of endogenous factors you'd see the same behavior. The distinction is in the presentation of the factor rather than the response of the system.